# How to refresh components when parent state changes in react when using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have the parent component called `App`. It holds the state and the form which changes the state.

I removed the unimportant code. When I type something in the form, an object item is added in the `state.item` but the `ToCompleteItemsComponent` doesn't update. Is there a way to update that component on state change

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: []
  }
    submitItem=(e)=> {
      e.preventDefault();
      let items = this.state.items;
      items.push({
        name: this.state.ValuePlaceholder,
        completed: false
      });
      this.setState({
        items

      });
    }

  render() {

    return (<BrowserRouter>
      <div className="wrap">
        ...
       <form onSubmit={this.submitItem}>
          <input type="text" />
        </form>
            <Route exact path="/"
                render={props => <ToCompleteItemsComponent 
                 items={this.state.items} /> }
                />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );

  }
}
```

**Edit** This is the component

```
class ToCompleteItemsComponent extends Component {
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
// check this.props vs nextProps and setState!
// do whatever you want.
  console.log(nextProps)
}
render(){
  return(<div>
  <ul className="items">
  {
    this.props.items.map( (item,id)=> <li key={id}>{item.name} <span>x</span></li>)
  }
  </ul>
  </div>)
}
}
export default ToCompleteItemsComponent;
```

`console.log(nextProps)` returns an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the parent state updates you can use: **[componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)**

in **ToCompleteItemsComponent** you can do this:

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // check this.props vs nextProps and setState!
  // do whatever you want.
}
```

As you can see in this snippet the console.log works as intended. I reworked the way you add stuff to your items array. Please have in mind I removed the **exact** attribute from the Route because in snippets I can't use Routes properly with BrowserRouter.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: []
  }
    submitItem=(e)=> {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.concat([{
          name: this.state.ValuePlaceholder,
          completed: false
        }])
      });
    }

  render() {
    return (<ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter>
      <div className="wrap">
       <form onSubmit={this.submitItem}>
          <input type="text" />
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </form>
            <ReactRouterDOM.Route path="/"
                render={props => <ToCompleteItemsComponent 
                 items={this.state.items} /> }
                />
      </div>
      </ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter>
    );

  }
}

class ToCompleteItemsComponent extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // check this.props vs nextProps and setState!
  // do whatever you want.
    console.log("HALO", this.props, nextProps)
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
    <div>
      <ul className="items">
      {
        this.props.items.map( (item,id)=> <li key={id}>{item.name} <span>x</span></li>)
      }
      </ul>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router/umd/react-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: `nextProps` returns an empty array!

Comment: @relidon The only reason I can think of right now is because this.state.items is an empty array.

Comment: can you look at the updated question, I added the component. Just to check if i'm missing something

Comment: @relidon I can only help you tomorrow but it might be related to you mutating the state in the submit function. Try using the concat method to add things to a new array and then setting the state. Please console.log this props on willReceiveProps and tell me what it has

Comment: With concat it now both `this.props` and `nextProps` return the old state. Will also work in it tomorrow.

Comment: @relidon I have updated the answer with a working snippet for your case.

Comment: It seems the actul problem is tht I filter the state when I pass it as prop.